# Is it possible to run a Rails controller method with runner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a Rails 4 application that keeps track of usage counters in a piece of equipment, so my controller has a method, record_usage, that can be interactively invoked from a view to immediately retrieve and record the usage counter. But, I also want to run the same method periodically, so I extract the code into a stand-alone .rb file and run it periodically via cron with

```
rails r -e production record_usage.rb
```

My question is: in the interest of "DRY" can I invoke the controller method directly from within 'record_usage.rb', rather than maintaining a separate copy of the record_usage code in the .rb file?

Comment: Sounds like a violation of 'Single Responsibility'... Any reason you can't extract that method to a separate helper/library/model and use it from there?  You can't easily do this without running into possible problems around request assumptions (depending on what assumptions your controller actually makes).

Comment: You may want to use something like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). Moreover you can wrap your code in a class; a model (without ActiveRecord) should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You don't invoke controller methods externally unless you want seven years of bad luck and the wrath of the MVC gods!

The public API of a controller is the actions that respond to HTTP requests. EVERYTHING else should be a private method.

Remember that the role of a controller in MVC is a class that takes a request and returns a response. Thus its not the place to shove all those little utilities.

In fact if you want to call something externally from your controller that is very strong signal that your controller is *fat* and that you should refactor by moving business logic into the model layer.

Aslo using single purpose objects known as service objects is a good way to clean up controllers that coincidentally lends itself very well to rake tasks and unit testing:

```
module CleanupService
  def self.call(foo)
    foo.dot_the_is
    foo.cross_the_ts 
  end
end
```

Not everything in MVC has to be a model, view or controller. Thats just the backbone.